# Stop Talkback, saying Webview after it loads

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, accessibility

Similar question has been asked previously too, but it's long time ago and having no answers.
First time when the webview gets loaded , talkback says webview but I want it to say nothing.
I tried setting content description in XML

```
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="CustomText"
```

but it still says Webview in the end.
Also tried `importantForAccessbility`no but it disables talkback to read the content too. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have the same requirement. Do we have a solution on this one?

Answer (score -2):

Just replace your webview with below webview xml code.Adding importantForAccessibility does everything for you.

```
   <WebView
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textContent"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I think he needs to read the Webview Content, and your solution is avoiding it.